# Good practice default values

Tags: python, python-2.7, tuples, default-value

I have several transportation brands, for each one I would like to specify all the available
 models as well as the default model.

So I first defined tuples this way:

```
SUZUKI = ('model_1', 'model_2', 'model_3')
FERRARI = ('model_1', 'model_2')
# etc
```

I would like to specify a default model for each brand. The thing is that with so many brands,
it would be tedious to define a default variable for each one of them:

```
SUZUKI_DEFAULT = 'model_1'
FERRARI_DEFAULT = 'model_2'
# etc
```

and so on. So I wonder what would be a good, not too shabby solution to tackle this issue.
Creating a class for each brand may be a waste of ressource as I don't need more 
additional parameters nor functions.

I thought of doing something like this, putting the default value at the end of the tuples, 
then specifying the position of the default value:

```
DEFAULT_POSITION = -1
SUZUKI = ('model_1', 'model_2', 'model_3', 'model_1')
FERRARI = ('model_1', 'model_2', 'default_model')
PORSCH = ('model_1', 'model_2', None)
# etc
```

I would then make a check statement such as:

```
if arg not in SUZUKI:
    arg = SUZUKI[DEFAULT_POSITION]
```

My question is, is that a bad practice, are there other solutions around, if not better?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you can't put the default as the 1st element in each?  Do you need a different order for some reason?

Comment: Not at all, that is the reason why I put the `DEFAULT_POSITION` variable for more visibility. Maybe it is actually useless I don't know :)

Comment: Can the down-vote be explained to me, so that I have hints to where to improve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not using a dictionary, seems to me like the better way to go. The code itself will get more understandable and easier.

```
brands = {'Suzuki':['model_1', 'model_2'], 'Ferrari':['model_1', 'model_2']}
```

And then just call them normally:

```
brands['Suzuki']
```

Outputs:

```
['model_1', 'model_2']
```

Comment: Thanks alas I don't see any benefit to using a dic. Besides, how would I include my default values for each brand, the subject of my question? It would complicate things I think.

Comment: Unless I use a dict of dicts as suggested by Jim... Pardon me.

Comment: @kaligne, also instead of repeating strings inside the dictionary and creating dicts inside dicts. You could just make the `[0]` of the list, for example `brands['Suzuki'][0]` the default value. And when you want another one to become the default value, you can index it at 0 and do this process over and over and over.

Comment: This answer probably best suits the needs of my program. Making a class ia a good idea but does not "feet" in my program logic, it would be useless.

Answer (score 1):

You could make a class:

```
class Brand(object):
    def __init__(*models, default=None):
        self.models = *models
        self.default = default
        assert default is None or default in models
```

Then use it:

```
SUZUKI = Brand('model_1', 'model_2', 'model_3', default='model_1')
FERRARI = Brand('model_1', 'model_2', default='model_2')
PORSCH = Brand('model_1', 'model_2', default=None)
```